# Writing line breaks to a <span> element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to take an array, and write each element onto a HTML page using a `<span>` element with `.textContent` using a for loop. Only problem is that instead of:

```
Error1
Error2
```

I get:

```
Error1<br/>Error2<br/>
```

HTML code:

```
<p><span id="EBox"></span></p>
```

JS code:

```
var EBox = document.getElementById("EBox");
var eArray = []; //Elements get added via push

for (var i = 0; i < eArray.length; i++) {
    EBox.textContent = EBox.textContent + eArray[i] + '<br/>';
}
```

The entire system works, but it just ends up as one jumbled sentence. What can I change to make it add the line breaks? I've tried `'<br>'`, `'<br />'`  and `'\n'` with similar results.

Comment: Please show how your eArray elements look like.

Comment: You can't use `.textContent` for this, because that's just text without any HTML rendering.

Answer (score 3):

Use <s>`.innerHTML`</s> [`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of `.textContent` as `.textContent` does not parse the HTML `<br>` but simply outputs it as text.

Also if you're appending to the HTML each time, it's better to use `.insertAdjacentHTML` as it does not reparse the previous HTML, thus making it much faster and less error prone than `.innerHTML`.

```js
var strArr = ['foo', 'bar'];

strArr.forEach(function(str) {
  document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Didn't know about .insertAdjacentHTML - nice call :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.textContent` use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

I would also recommend building up a string first before using `.innerHTML` so the DOM isn't rebuilt each time...

```
var EBox = document.getElementById("EBox");
var eArray = []; //Elements get added via push

var html = "";    
for (var i = 0; i < eArray.length; i++) {
    html += eArray[i] + '<br/>';
}
EBox.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better answer here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

You can use CSS to do this, see below:

```
span{word-break: break-word;}
```

or

```
span{word-break: break-all;}
```

BREAKE-WORD will put the next word in a new line and BREAKE-ALL will break the text justifying the content, when it gets bigger than the div or span container.

I hope I'd help :)